# horizontal calendar view in swift 3 or objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, calendar

i am working on project were i need a horizontal calendar view on top of my screen. In that calendar a total number of 15 dates will be displaying (last 7 days from current day and 7 upcoming days from current days)

Example: The current date is 22 Dec so it should be displaying like this :
`-15,16,17,18,19,20,21,(22->CurrentDate),23,24,25,26,27,28,29.` i have done research and i can't find horizontal view calendar  like this horizontal calendar made for android.

[Here is the GitHub Repo for this](https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar)

**Thanks in advance**.

Comment: suppose current date is 4 then what should be output ?

Comment: i am owning the api on date changed it is getting the list of data according to the selected date

Comment: i am asking because if current date is 4 then you need to show previous months some dates

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/didatepicker ? https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Calendar You have to do it yourself if you don't find one, any tries on your side?

Comment: You can checkout this one may be it'll be helpful for you :
https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: @NiravKotecha yes it will show previous month date.

Comment: @PradeepKashyap yes i have gone through that but didn't work

Comment: @Larme yes i tried as much i can at the end i posted it here

Comment: @DipakSingh: If you are looking for a "all done" external lib: SO is not the place for that kind of question. If you are looking "How could I replicate this object", check UICollectionView for instance, check the other libs in iOS (external) that do something like that, and look at their code.

Comment: @Larme thanks Bro i'll follow your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be quite simple on iOS, all you would need is a `UICollectionView` where each `cell` is an entry on the calendar with a `UILabel` with some attributed text in.

Comment: i did this to  but it is a bit tricky the date should be selected only in center check this link:- https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar

Comment: You can use the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method to determine which cell is central and change the cell based on that, that allows you to show the bottom bar indicator/adjust the font.

Comment: @ Nicholas Smith Ok Bro Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have fixed this issue. However you can use this library and customise as per your need !!

https://github.com/shahshrenik/Horizontal_Calendar

[image: Sample Flow]